# OPC DA disconnect and reconnect automatically after 20-30 seconds

Tags: opc, opc-da

We are having AIM.OPC Server, which is connected to a firewall and then to a data diode.
After several hours, AIM.OPC disconnects at Data diode and reconnect automatically after 20-30 seconds.
This repeating all the time. 6-7 times in a day.

When we capture NCAP using Wireshark, below message we received.
192.178.192.1 192.178.168.2 TCP 60 49157 -> 59021 {FIN, ACK} SEW=273 Ack=740 Win=65024 Len=0.

here 192.178.192.1 is my OPC Client
192.178.168.2 is my Data diode station.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue, not to disconnect from AIM.OPC